# Which one will give fast result in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Which eloquent statement will give a fast result?

```
$getData = User::selectRaw('user_name')->where('user_id',1)->first();

$getData = User::where('user_id',1)->first();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent ORM vs Query builder which one better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105249/laravel-eloquent-orm-vs-query-builder-which-one-better)

Comment: @N69S I read this article from http://theredfoxfire.github.io/2018-06-10-when-you-need-to-use-laravel-eloquent-or-not.html and here  https://inneka.com/programming/laravel/laravel-eloquent-vs-query-builder-why-use-eloquent-to-decrease-performance/ didnt see its referanced to stackoverflow question which is this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820024/12232340 you can get more infos there, and its duplicate question so I will remove my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the difference on performance is negligible. To make the query faster, you need the field `user_id` to be indexed in your database.