# how to use exact pivot table relationship

Tags: php, laravel

i have four table in database(sql):

customers Table:

```
id
name
```

credits Table:

```
id
name
count
```

customer_credit Table (pivot table):

```
customer_id
credit_id
expiry_date
```

consumers Table:

```
id
customer_id
```

this is the SPA application(Web base) with laravel.
how to received (only login customers) records from consumers table who conditions in customer_credit table available records without expire date for we can computing remaining credits. more explain is we are trying to gathering entrance and exit logs from guests in our pool and gym   and we want to gets count in credits table who exact customer_credit table id .

Comment: can you please check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First option, to use [**Laravel Query Builder**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries):

```
DB::table('consumers')
     ->select('consumers.*')
     ->join('customers', 'consumers.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
     ->join('customer_credit', 'customers.id', '=', 'customer_credit.customer_id')
     ->join('credits', 'customer_credit.credit_id', '=', 'credits.id')
     ->where('credits.count', '>', 0)
     ->where('customer_credit.expiry_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
     ->get();
```

Second option, to use [**Laravel Eloquent**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships). If you choose the second one and need help, you should share your model structures here.

Also read this topic to see the differences: [Laravel Eloquent vs query builder - Why use eloquent to decrease performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391710/laravel-eloquent-vs-query-builder-why-use-eloquent-to-decrease-performance)