# Is the Model still be useful if I use Query Builder instead of Eloquent ORM in Laravel using Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to use Query Builder because my project have many tables in the database, is it necessary to use Model if I use Query Builder?

Base in the article below, the Query Builder is much faster in processing in large scale of project.

[Query Builder VS Eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391710/laravel-eloquent-vs-query-builder-why-use-eloquent-to-decrease-performance)

Answer (score 2):

You won't have to use Model if you're using Query Builder.

Let's say you have a table named 'users' in your database. 
Just use it as below:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('loginname');
```

Comment: that makes it clear, because i'm new to laravel, other php framework uses model

Answer (score 1):

As mention by @kurapika, When using Query Builder, you do not need to use the Model. 
For example, with Model

```
$users = Users::get(['first_name']);
```

And using the query builder

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get(['first_name']);
```

There is no best choice. It depends solely on your need.