# Is there an alternate way to use findorfail() on updating with stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, bootstrap-4

I'm getting an error :

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\SqlServerConnection::find()"

I'm trying to update a table that was executed using stored procedure.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $cont = DB::find($request->ContainerId);

    $cont->update($request->all());

    return back();
}
```

I wanted to update a record in SQL Server but no luck at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB` is in general an anti pattern in `Laravel` applications and the `DB` does not have a `find` method either, it has methods for raw `SQL` queries.

Instead utilize your model, use the static methods there (like find or findOrFail). The table name is generated from a pluralized version on the class name, so the table name should be `containers`

```
public class Container extends Model {
}

Container::find($request->ContainerId);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 way for find( select one row ) from SQL :

1. ### Using Query Builder ( DB facade )

You need define table first :

```
$cont = DB::table("your_table_name_here")->find($request->ContainerId);
```

2. ### Using Eloquent

You need to use your Model :

```
$cont = YourModelHere::find($request->ContainerId);
```

or for handling exceptions :

```
$cont = YourModelHere::findOrFail($request->ContainerId);
```

I hope this helps you !

**Edit : 2019/05/26**

### Which is better ?

For Find or work with **few** records :

> i prefer to use Eloquent because its simple , easy , more readable and its for all types of SQL !  ( Thanks to [Martin Henriksen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5147920/martin-henriksen) comment)

In **General** :

> [Why we should use Query Builders for **lots of records** instead of Eloquent ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307841/speed-up-eloquent-query/56310602#56310602)

Comment: You are correct, but in general i think it is a bad habit to utilize DB table logic in your app, it goes against the way Laravel is intended.

Comment: Nice , Eloquent is another way ! But we cant recommend always eloquent ! I'm agree with you in this situation Eloquent is better because result is only one row ! But in deeper comparison Eloquent is not good for lots of records . Edited ! Thank you !