# Printing number of rows in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to print number of rows in Laravel from MySQL but i get this error: 
**htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\wamp64\www\kont\resources\views\profile.blade.php)**

I have two function inside my model. First function returns information about user from one table and another function counts number of friends for that user from another table. Please view my code below:

**HomeController.php**

```
public function profile(Request $request,$id){
        $model = new UserModel();
 $podaciIzBaze = $model->userdata($id);
 $data = array();
 $data['dt'] = $podaciIzBaze;

$model2 = new UserModel();
 $podaciIzBaze2 = $model2->countfriends($id);

 $data['dt2'] = $podaciIzBaze2;

         return view('profile',$data);

    }
```

**UserModel.php**

```
  class UserModel extends Model
    {
        //
        public function userdata($id){
            $query = DB::select("SELECT first_name,last_name,email,website,birth_date FROM users where id = $id");
            return $query;
        }

        public function countfriends($id){

            $query=DB::SELECT("SELECT count(user_id) from user_friend where user_id = $id");
            return $query;

        }
```

**profile.blade.php**

```
 @foreach($dt as $d)
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>Ime:</td>
                                    <td>{{ $d->first_name }}</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>Prezime</td>
                                    <td>{{ $d->last_name }}</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>Datum Rodjenja</td>
                                    <td>{{ $d->birth_date }}</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>Pol</td>
                                    <td>Musko</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>Email</td>
                                    <td><a href="mailto:info@support.com">{{ $d->email }}</a></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <td>Website</td>
                                 <td>
                                   {{ $d->website }}
                                 </td>
                                 </tr>
                                     @endforeach


                       @foreach($dt2 as $d2)
                     Number of friends: {{ $d }}
                     @endforeach
```

Comment: `as $d2)` but print `$d`. Are you sure?

Comment: I have replaced it with $d2 and get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line

```
@foreach($dt2 as $d2)
    Number of friends: {{ $d }}  // Here it should be $d2
@endforeach
```

It should be $d2 instead of $d.

**Edit 1**

Problem is with your second function countfriends($id). Use following code

```
$query=\DB::select("SELECT count(user_id) as friends from user_friend where user_id = $id");
```

Then in view file use:

```
@foreach($dt2 as $d2)
    Number of friends: {{ $d2->friends }}
@endforeach
```

When you were using select query it was returning the key "count(user_id)" which could not be used with standard object to print.

But you should start using Eloquent for queries instead of writing manual SQL queries.

Comment: I have replaced it with $d2 and get the same error.

Comment: Your solution worked great for me! Why do you think i should use Eloquent over manual SQL? Thanks.

Comment: Please go though this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897636/13642447 once.

Answer (score 0):

The DB::select returns an array of results.  You should use

```
$data['dt'] = $podaciIzBaze[0];
```

However, a more elegant way of doing this is as follows:

```
$data['dt'] = UserModel::find($id);
```

The find method returns the first row of the model in which the primary key equals $id

Answer (score 0):

`Number of friends: {{ $d }}` should be `Number of friends: {{ $d2 }}`

I suggest the following changes to your code:

1. Rename `UserModel` to just `User`
2. Add `Friend` model
3. Add eloquent relation of one to many between `User` model and `Friend` model
4. Rename table name `user_friend` to `user_friends` - this way you can utilise laravel's magic
5. `dt` and `dt2` are not descriptive - I have no idea what they represent, I would suggest renaming them to:
   `dt` -> `userData`
   `dt2` -> `totalFriends`

```
public function profile(User $user){
    $userData = $user->only([
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'website',
        'birth_date',
    ]);

    return view('profile', [
        'userData' => $userData,
        'totalFriends' => $user->friends->count(),
    ]);

}
```

Blade file would then look similar to:

```
 <tr>
    <td>Ime:</td>
    <td>{{ $userData->first_name }}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Prezime</td>
    <td>{{ $userData->last_name }}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Datum Rodjenja</td>
    <td>{{ $userData->birth_date }}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Pol</td>
    <td>Musko</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:info@support.com">{{ $userData->email }}</a></td>
 </tr>
 <td>Website</td>
     <td>
       {{ $userData->website }}
     </td>
 </tr>


 Number of friends: {{ $totalFiends }}
```

Comment: I have replaced it with $d2 and get the same error.

Comment: I would suggest refactoring per my comment. $d2 is where data is, if you do dd($dt2 ) within your controller you will see what $dt2 contains