# Should I use Laravel Eloquent in this situation or Query Builder?

Tags: php, laravel, web

Should I use Query Builder for this in Laravel 9?

```
 DB::table('galleries')->insert(
 ['book_id' => $book->id, 'photo' => $name, 'cover' => 1],
 );
```

or Laravel Eloquent?

```
Gallery::create(
['book_id' => $book->id, 'photo' => $name, 'cover' => 1],
);
```

And what is the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent vs DB facade: Why use Eloquent and decrease performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391710/laravel-eloquent-vs-db-facade-why-use-eloquent-and-decrease-performance)

Comment: No, It does not answer my question. Keep scrolling.

Comment: tl;dr - with DB no model events and no relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### insert() Query builder method difference:

1. the difference is, Query Builder `insert()` runs `mysql` raw insert query under the hood and As like `mysql` raw query you can create multiple rows in single query.

```
 DB::table('galleries')->insert(
 ['book_id' => $book->id, 'photo' => <photo A path>, 'cover' => 1],
 ['book_id' => $book->id, 'photo' => <photo B path>, 'cover' => 0],
 );
```

The above query will insert two rows in single query.

2. The second thing is, It is very fast and optimize in speed as compare to eloquent builder `create()` method.
3. Third, It's not emits `model events` i.e. `creating`, `created` events etc.
4. It's not returns created models in result.

##### `create()` eloquent method Difference:

1. It's insert only single row at a time. whenever you want insert multiple rows/models then you need to run `create()` method in `foreach loop` or needs to use `createMany()` method.

> All of them works same like `create()`. let suppose you want to insert 100 rows in database table then both will runs `100 insert` queries under the hood.

2. It emits [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events) i.e. `creating`, `created` events etc.
3. It returns inserted model in result.
4. It's slower than `insert()` query builder method because it's handling a lot of computations, events pipelines during insertion.

##### Suggestion:

If you want to catch model event then must use `eloquent()`. If you want query optimization, fast insertion and doesn't have any concern with `model events` then user `insert()` method.

Answer (score 2):

They are both basically the same. The only difference comes when you want to insert a huge amount of data.

The performance of query builder is much faster than that of the eloquent ORM when handling VERY LARGE amounts of data.